# Help Interpreting regression analysis of 2 models

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, inference

I'm being asked to compare 2 data sets and their regression model outcomes, and pick one that is stronger to rely on for future regression analysis, and explain why.

Here are the summaries of the 2 regression analyses:

1st  -Calreg data set

```
summary(calreg)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y, data = nocal)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2025.27  -378.33    20.02   523.08  1170.49 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -898.50210  679.72309  -1.322    0.198    
y              0.91167    0.06538  13.943 1.41e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 879.3 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.882, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8775 
F-statistic: 194.4 on 1 and 26 DF,  p-value: 1.406e-13
```

2nd tuition reg data set:

```
 summary(tuitionreg)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2262.7  -897.8   282.9  1024.2  1965.5 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 543.33834  957.55584   0.567    0.575    
y             0.73051    0.08819   8.283 2.35e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1312 on 31 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6888,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6787 
F-statistic: 68.61 on 1 and 31 DF,  p-value: 2.347e-09
```

Can someone help me interpret these model summaries?
Which is better to rely on? And how do you know?

Comment: Both models provide a significant fit, The first model has a lower p-value and residual error thus is it is a better fit given everything else is equal.  With no understanding the where the data came from, the range of the data and what the prediction is, my comment above is just a guess.

Comment: Your task doesn't make sense. What does "stronger to rely on for future regression analysis" even mean?